# Unable to install rmagick in Windows Machine

Tags: ruby

I am new to rmagick and ruby. I am using ruby 1.8.6 version

Actually i downloaded rmagic2.9.0 win32 version and i unzipped it and i installed imageMagic-6.4.8. Then from command prompt i gave gem update --system.

```
C:\>gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update
```

then

```
C:\>gem install rmagick --local
ERROR:  could not find gem rmagick locally or in a repository
```

then try giving

```
C:\>gem list --remote --all rmagick

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

rmagick (2.9.1, 2.9.0, 2.8.0, 2.7.2, 2.7.1, 2.7.0, 2.6.0, 2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2
.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.0, 1.15.17, 1.15.16, 1.15.15, 1.15.14, 1.1
5.13, 1.15.12, 1.15.11, 1.15.10, 1.15.9, 1.15.8, 1.15.7, 1.15.6, 1.15.5, 1.15.4,
 1.15.3, 1.15.2, 1.15.1, 1.15.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.0, 1.13.0, 1.12.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.0,
 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.3, 1.9.2, 1.9.1, 1.9.0, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.4,
1.7.3, 1.7.2, 1.7.1)
rmagick4j (0.3.7, 0.3.6, 0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1)
```

then

```
C:\>gem install rmagick -win32 -v 2.9.0
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This rmagick gem is for use only on Linux, BSD, OS X, and similar systems  |
| that have a gnu or similar toolchain installed. The rmagick-win32 gem is a |
| pre-compiled version of RMagick bundled with ImageMagick for use on        |
| Microsoft Windows systems. The rmagick-win32 gem is available on RubyForge.|
| See http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html for more information.    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/ruby/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/n32/gems/rmagick-2.9.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/n32/gems/rmagick-2.9.0/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

I am unable to install rmagick. Can any one please help me in solving ths problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

> C:>gem install rmagick --local ERROR: could not find gem rmagick locally or in a repository

That command has to be run from the directory where you unzipped the rmagick-win32 download.  Otherwise, gem won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall any Image Magick or RMagick gem from before.
2. Download rmagick-win32 for windows that has the gem and the ImageMagick installer from http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/64917/RMagick-2.12.0-ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8.zip
3. Unzip the rmagick-win32 zip file that you downloaded above.
4. Install the ImageMagick from the installer that came in the zip i.e. run the ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8-windows-dll.exe. This will install ImageMagick for you.
5. Install the rmagic gem that came in the zip i.e. rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32.gem.